# Git (скорее всего) неверно считает файл модифицированным

Tags: git

Привет.
Форкнул репу, переделал все что хотел, хочу синхронизировать ее согласно [этому](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork) сценарию перед отправкой пулреквеста. В процессе выясняется, что один из файлов у меня выводится как модифицированный, и мне нужно с ним что-то сделать перед слиянием. `git stash`, `git reset HEAD -- <file>` и `git checkout HEAD -- <file>` не дали никакого эффекта (даже с `rm <file>` перед этим - файл удаляется, восстанавливается, и снова считается модифицированным). Что делать? Файл я коммитить не хочу, пушо его если кто и трогал, то только phpstorm (во время манипуляций был отключен и точно не влиял на вышеописанное поведение).

`update-index assume-unchanged` наверняка является выходом из ситуации, но прибегать к нему бы не хотелось, это какой-то неверный подход.

upd. git diff в качестве диффа выводит файл целиком и ругается на no newline at the end of file. Через хексдамп я вижу последним сиволом 0А, который вроде как lf, но почему-то в leafpad (блокноте) его нет, а если я его там и ставлю, то git diff начинает ругаться на то, что newline нет уже в оригинальном файле.

upd2. склонировал форкнутую репу "с белого листа", в ней все равно числится измененный файл. FML.

Comment: что за репа если не секрет ? 

git checkout origin/master  -- path/to/file

давайте я склонирую и скажу вам md5 этого файла
версию git еще скажите и операционку

Comment: > что за репа если не секрет ?

https://github.com/etki/BlogMVC

> git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file

пробовал, он начинает подсвечиваться зеленым в git status, но толку если его все равно никто не трогал

> давайте я склонирую и скажу вам md5 этого файла версию git еще скажите и операционку

файл mkFramework/public/js/main.js

гит 1.9.1

операционка lubuntu 14.04

Comment: файл в репе заканчивается на 7D  кажется вся ерунда из-за того-что окончания строк там кривые часть \r\n а часть просто \n

Comment: @eicto, это-то да, но как от него избавиться легальным методом? Пойду еще на винде попробую слить.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings помогает его бинарным сделать :) Баг сам забьешь ? я на irc сейчас спрашиваю про твой issue, т.к. это конкретно неправильное поведение.

Comment: @eicto пока я даже не представляю, куда

Comment: http://git-scm.com/community но лучше сначала поспрашивать, может они сами это сделают у меня вот такой тест есть http://pastebin.com/CzVt1hN6 (в свежем docker на debian-sid с git-2.1.0  сделал, 2.0 тоже пробовал) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10363472/815386 но я все равно не очень понимаю, почему так  происходит :)

Comment: @eicto, хорошо, попробую написать как просплюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел  шаманский workaround для вашего случая:

1. делаем clone
2. делаем  свои изменения
3. коментим  `* text=auto` в .gitattributes
4. git status
5. убираем коммент
6. git status
7. коммитим свои изменения.

это неудобно и неправильно, но на один раз сойдет, если хотите и дальше работать с этим репом сделайте им pull request с закоменченным  `* text=auto` в .gitattributes